How to Activate Hyperlink in Pop-up From Attribute Field
I am building expressions in a pop-up in AGOL Web Map. A specific field in the attribute table I am drawing from has URLs in each cell. When I drop the field name into the pop-up from the Fields List, it shows the URL in the pop-up but the it is not active, meaning the end user cannot click on it and go to the website.
Here is my input data in the Text :
Contract: {dotcms_factsheet}
The {dotcms_factsheet} comes from the Fields List pull down in the text editor in AGOL Web Map in the pop-up. In the cell for this object is the URL I need.
Here is what this shows in the pop-up:
Contract: http://dotcms:9080/bookmark.jsp?vsld
but the URL is not a hyperlink.
How can I make the hyperlink active in the pop-up?

Additionally, I created an Arcade element. Trying to add the element to the text, but cannot. It is not in the Fields List pull-down menu, but is an object at the bottom of the Pop-up Menu


Can you show any code you have used? The {All_Contract_Plan} is that just an attribute? Have you looked into using ARCADE to format the link?

Please don't use the word "hyperlink" when you mean "URL".  A hyperlink is something that can be clicked on to navigate to the resource defined by a URL.  If clicking on it does nothing, then it is not a hyperlink.  It is merely a URL.  So, what have you done to turn the text of the URL into a hyperlink in your pop-up?  In normal HTML, a hyperlink is usually defined by the HTML format:  <a href="http://domain.com/blah">link text</a>.  In your pop-up you may be able to do it something like:   <a href="{field_name}">click here</a>.  (But you would need to use the HTML editor for this.)

Hi, thank you. I haven't done anything to turn the text of the URL into a hyperlink. That's what I am trying to figure out.

You can use an Arcade element to create a clickable link, using this code:
var output = `Contract Plan: <a href="${$feature.dotcms_factsheet}">Link</a>`

return { 
    type : 'text', 
    text : output
}

Select the Arcade element from the Content list in the Pop-ups tab


Ok, thank you. I tried this. I created an expression and then inserted the expression into the text from the Fields List and it returns a table of 2 rows and 2 fields. The first row has a grey background:
text                                Contract Plan:Link
type                               text
It's not the real link for obvious reasons.

You have to use the Arcade element, not any of the other elements in the dropdown selection. I've added an image to highlight what you need to use.

Try this:
Go to the feature and click "Configure Popup"
Head to the expression window, and add one.
Type in the following Arcade Expression:
var url = $feature["URL_Field"]; // Replace 'URL_Field' with the name of your URL field
return url

You can hit the ">" buttong next to feature to get the fields:

Change the "Pop-up" contents to "A custom attribute display" and then Configure

In the new window, hit the "Source button"

Then you need to paste in some HTML code:
<a href="{expression/expr0}" target="_blank"> Field URL</a>

Hit ok all the way back.
Your popup will now show the url and have it clickable.

I did have some issues with the url and it seems AGOL like "https://www." as the format. "www." doesnt seem to work.

Hi, thanks for your help. I'm confused on two points:  1) Where you have "URL_Field" I don't know what the URL is. The URL is in a cell in a field named All_Contract_Plan in the attribute table for the object I click on. Each URL will be different for each cell and therefore each object. I want to pull the URL out of the cell and into the pop-up. And 2) I don't now how to change the "Pop-up" contents to "A custom attribute display" in ArcGIS Pro.

Hah! Almost there. I got the Arcade element to work, now I just need to place it in the text. The Arcade Element is located at the bottom of the Popups menu and is not included in the text. I do not see it in the Fields List like the expressions either. Any suggestions would be welcome. I've included an image of the Popup Menu above. Thank you.

Also, I am using Map Viewer and not Classic. How do I open the Custom Attribute Display in Map Viewer?
